# Automate Payment via Paypal (Sender is Business Account)

Tags: paypal

I have integrated Paypal API in my application

`$adaptivePaymentsService    = new AdaptivePaymentsService(Yii::app()->params['PaypalConfig']);`

The Paypal config has all the details of my business account.

i am searching for a code to do payment.. (but without approval of sender) as sender is the business account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adaptive Payments is old and deprecated, so you cannot use that. No live App ID for Adaptive Payments will be provided.

The owner of the business account can request access to PayPal Payouts. Here is information on that: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts